# How to work with a list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am working with the Robin-Stocks library

```
https://readthedocs.org/projects/robin-stocks/downloads/pdf/latest/
```

Particularly:

```
robin_stocks.robinhood.orders.get_all_open_stock_orders(info=None)
```

According to the documentation from the link above. This returns a list of dictionaries of key/value pairs. I am new to using python and don't really know how to work with this data. If I do this:

```
myData = rs.orders.get_all_open_stock_orders()
print(myData)
```

The simplified result is:

```
[{'id': 'foo', 'last': {'amount': '3.79', 'cod': 'USD'}, 'peg': {'tp': 'per', 'per': 15}, 'sid': 'sel'}, {'id': 'bar', 'last': {'amount': '4.22', 'cod': 'USD'}, 'peg': {'tp': 'per', 'per': 18}, 'sid': 'sel'}, {'id': 'tom', 'last': None, 'peg': None, 'sid': 'sel'}]
```

In reality, the list is much longer. Like I said, this is simplified. Just as the documentation says, it is a list of dictionaries of key/value pairs. For example there is a key 'id' and a value 'foo' and another key 'id' and a value 'bar' and another key 'id' and a value 'tom' and also there is a dictionary 'last': {'amount': '3.79', 'cod': 'USD'} and another dictionary 'last': {'amount': '4.22', 'cod': 'USD'} but sometimes the key 'last' has a value of None instead of a dictionary.

If I wanted to produce something like:

```
test = some code i don't know how to do
print(test)
```

Result:

```
       amount
foo    3.79
bar    4.22
tom    None
```

How would I do this?

Similarly, How would I get:

```
       peg
foo    15
bar    18
tom    None
```

Is it possible to produce this:

```
       amount     peg
foo    3.79       15
bar    4.22       18
tom    None       None
```

Comment: have a look at `pandas` library, it will solve your problem

Comment: I tried pandas... but was not able to figure out how to work with this list of nested dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
data = [{'id': 'foo', 'last': {'amount': '3.79', 'cod': 'USD'}, 'peg': {'tp': 'per', 'per': 15}, 'sid': 'sel'}, {'id': 'bar', 'last': {'amount': '4.22', 'cod': 'USD'}, 'peg': {'tp': 'per', 'per': 18}, 'sid': 'sel'}, {'id': 'tom', 'last': None, 'peg': None, 'sid': 'sel'}]
```

this:

```
test = [(d['id'], (d.get('last') or {}).get('amount'), (d.get('peg') or {}).get('per')) for d in data]
print('\tamount\tpeg\n' + '\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str, item)) for item in test))
```

produces:

```
    amount  peg
foo 3.79    15
bar 4.22    18
tom None    None
```

Note that this print statement only maintains column alignment as long as no field value exceeds the width of a TAB. A better approach would be to calculate each column's max field length and use the [width format specifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to format each column as a fixed width.